# why tensor.numpy() outputs different value?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I used tensor.numpy() on a feature matrix and a row of this matrix for comparison. I found the value is not the same for the row output and the corresponding row of the matrix. Anyone knows why?

```
def consine_distance_byrow(f1, f2):
    feat1 = f1.view(-1, 1)
    dists = torch.mm(f2, feat1)
    dists = dists.numpy()
    return dists

def consine_distance(f1, f2):
    feat1 = torch.transpose(f1, 0, 1)
    dists = torch.mm(f2, feat1)
    dists = dists.numpy()
    return dists

# load trainingset data
feature_path = '../../cnn/pytorch_result_train_val_' + str(self.feature_nums) + '.mat'
result = scipy.io.loadmat(feature_path)
train_feature = torch.FloatTensor(result['train_f']) # M x 512d
dists = consine_distance(train_feature, train_feature) # way1
for i in range(len(train_label)):
    distsT = consine_distance_byrow(train_feature[i], train_feature) # way2
    # here, dists[:,i] is slightly different with distsT
```

e.g.

```
dists[:0] = [ 1.0000001  -0.15086517 -0.08085391 ... -0.05950543 -0.03058994
  0.10164267]


while i=0, distT = [[ 0.99999964]
 [-0.15086518]
 [-0.0808539 ]
 ...
 [-0.05950541]
 [-0.03058996]
 [ 0.1016427 ]]
```

apparently, there is a slightly difference.

and this is caused after tensor.numpy(), before this step the two tensors are the same

Comment: Hey! Can you find a version that does not rely on the features you load from file? That would make our analysis easier.

Comment: I think this has to do with the limitation of float32 precision. have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/18427)